# Unknown Property Error in VF

Tags: apex, visualforce

Posting the markup from VF (*posting only the relevant section as my total VF page exceeds the allowed limit in SFSE*)

```
 <section id="section-line-8">

                            <apex:panelGrid id="history_section" columns="2" styleClass="factfind">
                              <apex:outputpanel id="no_rse" rendered="{! WrapperHistories.size == 0 || WrapperHistories == null }">
                                <p style="font-size:24px; text-align:center;color:#999999;"> No History Found </p>
                            </apex:outputpanel>
                            </apex:panelGrid>
                            <apex:outputPanel id="imp_his_section" rendered="{! WrapperHistories.size > 0 }">
                                    <table border="0" class="related_se">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><span class="title">Date</span></td>
                                            <td><span class="title">User</span></td>
                                            <td><span class="title">Action</span></td>

                                        </tr>                                    
                                        <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="rowNum" />
                                        <apex:repeat id="imp_h" value="{!WrapperHistories}" var="wh">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><apex:outputField value="{!wh.Implementation__History.CreatedDate}"/></td>
                                                <td><apex:outputField value="{!wh.Implementation__History.CreatedById}"/></td>
                                                <td>
                                                        <apex:outputText style="font-style:bold" value="Changed  "/>
                                                        <apex:outputText style="font-style:bold;color:blue;font-weight: bold;" value="{!wh.lbl}"/>
                                                        <apex:outputText style="font-style:bold" value="   from "/>
                                                        <apex:outputText style="font-style:bold;color:blue;font-weight: bold;" value="{!wh.Implementation__History.OldValue} "/>
                                                        <apex:outputText style="font-style:bold" value="to "/>
                                                        <apex:outputText style="font-style:bold;color:blue;font-weight: bold;" value="{!wh.Implementation__History.NewValue} "/>
                                                </td>


                                            </tr>
                                        </apex:repeat>
                                        <tr><td><br/></td></tr>

                                    </table>
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                        </section>
```

This is my controller

```
public class ImplementationController {

    public ApexPages.standardController st_controller;
   // public Implementation__c i{get;set;}
    public Implementation__c implementation{get; set;}
    public Implementation_Status__c CancelledStatus = Implementation_Status__c.getValues('Cancelled'); // Cancelled
    public Service_Enquiry_Settings__c ses_exit_url = Service_Enquiry_Settings__c.getValues('ExitURLImp');
    public List<String> li_Implementation_Nav_Bar{get; set;}
    public List<WrapperHistoryList> WrapperHistories{get;set;}

    public ImplementationController (ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
     st_controller = stdController;
     implementation = getImplementation(st_controller.getId());
     li_Implementation_Nav_Bar = getImplementationNavBar(implementation);
     //implementationhistories = getImplementationHistory(implementation);
      WrapperHistories = getImplementationHistory(implementation);  
        }

    public class WrapperHistoryList{
        public String lbl{get;set;}
        public Implementation__History ImplementationHistory{get;set;}

    }

    public String GetLabel(String fname)
    {
        String type='Implementation__c';
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Schema.SObjectType leadSchema = schemaMap.get(type);
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = leadSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        return fieldMap.get(fname).getDescribe().getLabel();
    }

    public List<WrapperHistoryList> getImplementationHistory(Implementation__c impe)
    {
        List<WrapperHistoryList> wlist = new List<WrapperHistoryList>();

        List<Implementation__History> imphis = [SELECT ID,NewValue,OldValue,ParentId,Field,CreatedDate,CreatedById FROM Implementation__History WHERE ParentId= :impe.Id ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];
        if(imphis.size()>0)
        {
            //return imphis;
            for(Implementation__History i : imphis)
            {
                WrapperHistoryList w = new WrapperHistoryList();
                w.ImplementationHistory = i;
                w.lbl = GetLabel(i.Field);
                wlist.add(w);
            }
            return wlist;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

   public Implementation__c getImplementation(String ImpId){

        Implementation__c imp = new Implementation__c();
        String queryStr = 'Select ' + CommonUsedClass.sObjectGetAllFields(imp).trim() + ' From Implementation__c Where Id = : ImpId';
        try{
           imp = Database.query(queryStr);     
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            system.debug('****** Querying Service Enquiry Exception: ' + e.getMessage()); 
        }
        return imp;
    }

    public List<String> getImplementationNavBar(Implementation__c impe){
        List<String> li_nav = new List<String>();
        for(SelectOption option : CommonUsedClass.getPicklistValue('Implementation__c', 'Implementation_Status__c')){
            // Active Nav Bar - without 'Lost' status
            if(impe.Implementation_Status__c != CancelledStatus.Status_Name__c){
                if(option.getValue() != CancelledStatus.Status_Name__c){
                    li_nav.add(option.getLabel());    
                }                 
            }
            else{
                li_nav.add(option.getLabel());
            }

        }
        return li_nav;
    }

  public PageReference saveImp(){

       System.debug('~~~ Before Update'); 
        update implementation;
        PageReference page = new PageReference('/' + ses_exit_url.URL__c);
        return page;

    }

    public PageReference exitImp(){
        PageReference page = new PageReference('/' + ses_exit_url.URL__c);
        return page;
    }


}
```

**Issue :**

I am getting an error while compiling the VF page.
The error is as follows

[image]

I am not able to understand why I am getting that error.
I am using a wrapper class list variable as source for `<apex:repeat>` and I believe my getter/setter definition is right and I should be able to reference the list variable in my VF page without any error.

Can someone let me know as to what I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines

```
<apex:repeat id="imp_h" value="{!WrapperHistories}" var="wh">
    <tr>
     <td><apex:outputField value="{!wh.Implementation__History.CreatedDate}" ...
```

can be deconstructed as:

`{!WrapperHistories}` references a list of type `WrapperHistoryList`

`wh` is thus bound to a specific list element of type `WrapperHistoryList`

`WrapperHistoryList` is defined as an inner class:

```
public class WrapperHistoryList{
    public String lbl{get;set;}
    public Implementation__History ImplementationHistory{get;set;}

}
```

and has two properties:

`lbl` and `ImplementationHistory` (the latter of type `Implementation__History`

thus, when using `wh` in the repeat markup, the only things you can use are:

`{!wh.lbl}` and `{!wh.ImplementationHistory.xxx}` where `xxx` are fields on that Sobject

Answer (score 2):

Your Visualforce needs to reference the property *name* `ImplementationHistory` not the property *type* `Implementation__History`.